# Argument of type "Literal[1]" cannot be assigned to parameter "self" of type "clock" in function "tick" "Literal[1]" is incompatible with "clock"

Tags: python-3.x

I get an error saying that I am not giving the value for self when i gave my code as follows:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))
clock = pygame.time.Clock
running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(1)
```

The error from terminal was:
clock.tick(1)
TypeError: descriptor 'tick' for 'Clock' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
error given vs code:

```
Argument of type "Literal[1]" cannot be assigned to parameter "self" of type "clock" in function "tick"
"Literal[1]" is incompatible with "clock"
```

Please help I don't know what to do
I tried to make the game have a tick of 1 but it gives an error saying int is not correct I tried giving other variables but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same problem and I know that the author has probably gone over this and I'm too late, the problem is that on the line

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock
```

you have not put parenthesis after `Clock`

it needs to be

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

---

PS, funny how I answered this question almost exactly after 1 year of it being posted.